# Read a Smil File

Tags: html, epub, smil, epub3

I have a page in my epub3 document with a few lines of text. When the user presses a line, I play the audio associated with this line using a html5 audio element. All of the audio is stored in one mp3/ogg file. So rather than defining the start and end times of each line in javascript, I was thinking I could define them in a smil file. Should I read in the smil file using the Html5 File API or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

By using, Smil file you can read the line using audio file.

In HTML code, you need to split the sentence into word eg. w01, w02 .... and create smil file, here in page3.mp3 using **ClipBegin** and **ClipEnd** split the clip seconds according to that words. (you can use audio editor such as GoldWave to split clip seconds). Add the below code to your package file.

HTML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" 
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=623, height=911" />
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Page 03</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page3_item1">
<span id="w01">Some</span> <span id="w02">animals</span> <span id="w03">hide</span> 
<br/><span id="w04">to</span> <span id="w05">stay</span> <span id="w06">safe</span> 
<span id="w07">from</span> <span id="w08">enemies</span>.</div>
<audio id="myaudio">
<source src="audio/page3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

SMIL File Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/SMIL" version="3.0" 
xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<body>
<par id="p_w01"><text src="p03.xhtml#w01"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="0s" clipEnd="10s"/></par>
<par id="p_w02"><text src="p03.xhtml#w02"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="11s" clipEnd="18s"/></par>
<par id="p_w03"><text src="p03.xhtml#w03"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="19s" clipEnd="24s"/></par>
<par id="p_w04"><text src="p03.xhtml#w04"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="25s" clipEnd="35s"/></par>
<par id="p_w05"><text src="p03.xhtml#w05"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="36s" clipEnd="40s"/></par>
<par id="p_w06"><text src="p03.xhtml#w06"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="41s" clipEnd="48s"/></par>
<par id="p_w07"><text src="p03.xhtml#w07"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="49s" clipEnd="58s"/></par>
<par id="p_w08"><text src="p03.xhtml#w08"/><audio src="audio/page3.mp3"  
clipBegin="59s" clipEnd="65s"/></par>
</body>
</smil>
```

Package File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package>
<metadata>
<meta property="media:duration" refines="#p03smil">0:00:04.600</meta>
</metadata>

<manifest>
<item id="page3" href="audio/page3.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg"/>
<item id="p03smil" href="smil/p03.smil" media-type="application/smil+xml"/>
</manifest>
```